# Limit of function calculations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, rational-functions

I must solve limit of next function:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2x^3+x-2}{3x^3-x^2-x+1}$$
Does my calculations are proper? If not where is my mistake?
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^3\left(2+\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x^3}\right)}{x^3\left(3-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)} \\
\ =\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^3\left(2+0-0\right)}{x^3\left(3-0-0+0\right)} \\
\ =\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Actually, this is not correct (that is, the work is not correct).  You can't take part of the limit in some places and not do it everywhere.  To do it correctly, you should cancel the $x^3$ first, then take the limit.

Comment: Using l'hopital 3 times can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly correct! In the future you can also check your work on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x%20-%3E%20infinity%20(2x%5E3%2Bx%E2%88%922)%2F(3x%5E3%E2%88%92x%5E2%E2%88%92x%2B1)).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your calculations look correct. However, for future reference, there is an easier way to do this. If you have a rational function with a polynomial on the top and bottom and  you are taking the limit as $x \to \infty$:

- If the polynomials are of the same degree, then the limit is the ratio of their leading coefficients
- If the polynomial in the numerator has a higher degree, the limit is $\infty$.
- If the polynomial in the denominator has a higher degree, the limit is $0$.

Comment: This is nice, but I do not know which one is degree, which one is numerator and which is denominator. Can you include some example please. First - I understand that: since $x^3$ for both so answer is $\frac{2}{3}$;

Comment: The *degree* of a polynomial is the highest exponent of one of its terms. For example, the degree of $x^2+x+1$ is $2$ and the degree of $x^5+x^3-x$ is $5$. The *numerator* of a fraction is "what is on top" or what is being divided, and the *denominator* is "what is on the bottom" or what one is dividing by.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, if you have the ratio of two polynomial of the same degree $n$ then
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots +a_0}{b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots +b_0}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^n(a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\dots +\frac{a_0}{x^n})}{x^n(b_n+\frac{b_{n-1}}{x}+\dots +\frac{b_0}{x^n})}\\=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\dots +\frac{a_0}{x^n}}{b_n+\frac{b_{n-1}}{x}+\dots +\frac{b_0}{x^n}}=\frac{a_n+0+\dots +0}{b_n+0+\dots +0}=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$
where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are different from zero.

Answer (score 1):

Put $y=1/x $ and compute

$$\lim_ {y\to 0^+}\frac { 2+y^2-2y^3 }{3-y -y^2  +y^3}=2/3$$